# Gmail-api to send email though server

Tags: email, heroku, gmail-api, oauth-2.0

This is my sample code for sending a mail through a gmail id.When I deploy it on my eclipse tomcat, I am able to send email successfully.

But When I put the same code on heroku and pass the necessary params using a rest Api, I get this in my logs

Please open the following address in your browser:
[Auth URL](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=**********-mcuc6cogvbfjkkkh8nrb0jsp4m9pqh9n.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:41138/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.labels%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly%20https://mail.google.com)

When I hit this url, It ask me for consent to access the gmail for various scopes and I click on allow, then I get the error

> [Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
>   ErrorCode: 10061. 
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:41138

Please let me know what I am missing.

My code is here

```
public class GmailQuickstart {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
    "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
    System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/gmail-java-quickstart.json");

private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

private static final List<String> SCOPES =
    Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS,GmailScopes.GMAIL_COMPOSE, GmailScopes.GMAIL_INSERT, GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY, GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

private static final String HashMap = null;

static {
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in =
        GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
        GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                    HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
        flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
    System.out.println(
            "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
    return credential;
}

public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
private static MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String cc, String subject, String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress tAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    InternetAddress cAddress = cc.isEmpty() ? null : new InternetAddress(cc);
    InternetAddress fAddress = new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com");

    email.setFrom(fAddress);
    if (cAddress != null) {
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.CC, cAddress);
    }
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, tAddress);
    email.setSubject(subject);

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    htmlPart.setText(bodyText);
    mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
    email.setContent(mp);

    return email;
}

private static Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage email) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    email.writeTo(baos);
    String encodedEmail = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(baos.toByteArray());
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setRaw(encodedEmail);
    return message;
}


public static void sendMail(Map map) throws IOException, MessagingException {
    Map<String, String> template=null;
    if("welcome".equalsIgnoreCase((String)map.get("type"))){
        template= EmailTemplateReader.readTemplate("welcome");
    }else{
        String status = (String)(((HashMap) map.get("data")).get("status"));
        template = EmailTemplateReader.readTemplate(status.toLowerCase());
    }


    HashMap<String,String> dataMap = (HashMap<String,String>)map.get("data");
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : template.entrySet()) {

        String value=entry.getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> dataentry : dataMap.entrySet()) {
            value = value.replace("#" + dataentry.getKey() + "#", dataentry.getValue());
        }
        entry.setValue(value);  
    }

    Message m = createMessageWithEmail(createEmail((String)map.get("to"), (String)map.get("cc"),(String) template.get("subject"), (String) template.get("content")));
    getGmailService().users().messages().send("me", m).execute();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) or check proper authorization using OAuth 2.0 credentials and permission scopes? In addition to that, have you also checked if API restricted the IP addresses within your socket connection to localhost? Possible issues can either be that it's not whitelisted in the Restrict Key section or a firewall issue with Heroku.

Comment: Do I need to create the key as web application type in the Google API console ?

Comment: I have created credential of type "Calling Gmail API from a web server". But I didnt provided any redirect uri. When I run the url I get in my server console, I get t his "Error: redirect_uri_mismatch"